# Airpods Pro not switching between macbook and iphone, whereas works on ipad and iphone(both iOS/ipadOS 14 and mac big sur 11)

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ipad, airpods, ios

Airpods Pro not switching between Macbook and Iphone, whereas works on ipad and iphone(both ios 14 and mac big sur 11). The switch between macbook and iphone is manual whereas from ipad to iphone and vice versa is totally seamless. Do I need to enable the feature in mac somewhere?

Comment: I don't think the Mac supports automatic switching [according to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207010).  They only indicate manual switching on the Mac.

Comment: That is sad, hope they support that soon!